# angularjs date conversion map function not working ie

Tags: angularjs

I am using below function to convert date format

```
$http.get('/api/url').then(function(response){
            $scope.reports = response.data;
            $scope.reports = $scope.reports.map(obj =>{
                obj.created_at  = new Date(obj.created_at);
                return obj;
            });
        },function(error){
            console.log("error");
        });
```

It working fine all browser except **IE** I don't know what is the problem on this function

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? And can you post an example of the response json you are mapping? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `Arrow`/`Lambda` function in `map` tranform function that isn't supported on IE. Use `function` instead of `() => { ... }` or use babel or typescript.

```
$scope.reports = $scope.reports.map(function(){
    obj.created_at  = new Date(obj.created_at);
    return obj;
});
```

check [Arrow function](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) browser support

Comment: What's the issue?